# Number of missing values in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, missing-data

I have a data frame in `R` as follows:

```
gen    pos    count
A      1      10
A      2      20
A      3      15
A      4      
...
B      1      50
B      2      30
B      3      
B      4      40
...
```

The data frame contains ~30000 rows. Values for `count` are intentionally missing in ~300 rows. I plot these data with:

```
ggplot(data=d, aes(x=pos, y=count, group=gen, colour=gen)) + geom_line()
```

The missing data points are absent on the plot, which is what I want. I am happy with the plot.

However, `ggplot` returns the following warning:

```
Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
```

If there are ~300 missing values (for `count`; there are no missing values for `gen` or `pos`), why is `ggplot` reporting only 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a simple example:

```
df = data.frame(gen=rep(letters[1:3],each=6),
                y=c(NA,2,5,6,NA,8,9,NA,1,2,3,1,4,3,6.5,4.2,1,NA),
                x=rep(1:6,3))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=gen)) + geom_line()
```

And we have the warning:

```
Warning message:
Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
```

By looking at the graph below, we see that:

- For group **a**, the last point with coordinate `(6,8)` is absent despite it has no NA. We notice it is an 'isolated point' (cannot link it to the previous value `(5, NA)` which has `NA`).
- For group **b**, the first point is absent despite it has no `NA`. It is also an isolated point, cannot be linked to the next value since it has `NA`.
- For group **c**, the last point is absent but this is correct since it has an y value which is `NA`.

Hence the warning message just gives an indication of **how many regular (not NA) but isolated points are removed** from the graph. Here `2`.

[image]